# how to explain the execution results are different from node and brower

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout1');
  Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log('promise1');
  }).then(function() {
    console.log('promise2');
  })
}, 0);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout2');
  Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log('promise3');
  }).then(function() {
    console.log('promise4');
  })
}, 0);
```

the execution in the nodejs (6.10.2LTS) and Chrome's result are these two pictures. Left is node and the other is Chrome.

[image: node results]
[image: chrome results]

When I execute several times there will be above two different results in the node.
I have known that in browser runtimes we can explain event-loop by WhatWG and Promises/A+ Standard (task queues mechanism).

even through i have read the document like
[The Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/),
I still can't explain the different result by this two runtimes. The most important is how to explain nodejs's result.

Comment: Are you asking why in node you are getting inconsistent order (as shown in the picture), or are you asking how node differs from the browser (as asked in the title, but without presenting results)?

Comment: @Bergi I think I have known the reason of result in brower. So the important is in nodejs. Because I always think that node and chrome 's engine is same(v8) so the result should be same =。=

Comment: Yes, those node results are weird indeed. I'm curious as well.